# Firebase Auth taking a really long time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

For the past 24 hours (since Dec 6th 2023) all of the calls to `FirebaseAuth`, like `authInstance.currentUser`, `authInstance.signInWithCredential`, and `authInstance.isSignInWithEmailLink` take a really long time (we are talking 3-5 mins here). Calls eventually make it trough, and once the user is cached it works, but it is currently a really bad user experience.

Was there a configuration that recently changed that we missed on the Android side? Our firebase BOM version is `"32.2.0"`.

Update: I've also tried updating Firebase version to 32.6.0, and I see the same. For example, we trigger the following call at timestamp `1701974378898 - 2023-12-07 10:39:38.898`:

```
            PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(FirebaseAuthSource.authInstance)
                .setPhoneNumber("+$credentials") // Phone number to verify.
                .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout and unit.
                .setActivity(requireActivity()) // Activity (for callback binding).
                .setCallbacks(callbacks) // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks.
                .build()
            PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)
```

And by the time that `PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks().onCodeSend`  executes (which is part of the `callback` passed in above the timestamp is showing: `1701974621610 - 2023-12-07 10:43:41.611` . So that's whole 4 minutes later for the call to complete.

I'm seeing similar timeout for other calls to `FirebaseAuth` library.